# How to measure the cell width and height in tabular?

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, tikzmark

I need to draw some arrow marks in the border some cells in a tabular. That arrow should start from the bottom right corner of the cell and end at top right corner of the cell. I have drawn such arrows `tikzmark` and `calc` libraries. The following is my solution

```
\newcommand\cellarrow[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, >=stealth, shift={(0,0)}]
      \draw[->, line width=2pt,color =brown]  ( $ (pic cs:#1) +(2.7\tabcolsep,-1ex) $ )  to   ( $ (pic cs:#1) +(16pt,2.5ex) $ ) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    }
```

[image]

Obviously This is not a good solution since it works well width only a particular table shown in `Section 1`. So we need to some how position the bottom right corner and draw the arrow with the height same as that of the corresponding cell.

### How to do this?

Any idea is highly appreciated.

### MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark}


\newcommand\cellarrow[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, >=stealth, shift={(0,0)}]
  \draw[->, line width=2pt,color =brown]  ( $ (pic cs:#1) +(2.7\tabcolsep,-1ex) $ )  to   ( $ (pic cs:#1) +(16pt,2.5ex) $ ) ;
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\def\done{done}


    \begin{document}
    \section{Table with Same width}
            \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        Some column  & \done & \done &  \done&  \done& \done&\done \\
        \hline
        This has arrows&\tikzmark{a}   & \tikzmark{b} & \tikzmark{c} & & &  \\
        \hline
        Communication of Papers
        & &  & &  & &    \\ \hline  
    \end{tabular}
        \cellarrow{a} 
        \cellarrow{b} 
        \cellarrow{c} 



    \section{Some other table}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        Some column  & \done & \done &  \done&  \done&  \done& \done &\done  &\\
        \hline
        This has arrows&  &  &  &  & & \tikzmark{f} & \tikzmark{g} & \tikzmark{h} \\
        \hline
        Communication of Papers
        & &  & &  & &  & &  \\ \hline   
    \end{tabular}
    \cellarrow{f} 
    \cellarrow{g} 
    \cellarrow{h} 

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, `\end{document}`, and definitions of custom macros. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake happened and I didnt notice too. I have edited the question.

Comment: Tabulars use a strut of height \arraystretch\ht\strutbox and depth \arraystretch\dp\strutbox.  Of course, if the contents are larger than the strut, it will use the height and depth of the contents.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe in your case is more convenient to use a TikZ matrix.

I created a `\cellarrow` macro with two options: row and column of the cell where the arrow has to be drawn.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{
  mymatr/.style={
    matrix of nodes, 
    nodes in empty cells,
    nodes={draw, text centered, text width=width("\done")},
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    }
  }

\usepackage{xcolor}

\def\done{done}

\newcommand\cellarrow[2]{
  \draw[-stealth, line width=2pt, color=brown] (matr-#1-#2.south east) -- (matr-#1-#2.north east);
  }

\begin{document}
\section{Table with Same width}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[mymatr,
     column 1/.style={nodes={text width=width("Communication of Papers")}},
     nodes={text height=height("C"), text depth=depth("p")}
     ] (matr) {
     Some column & \done & \done & \done& \done& \done&\done \\
     This has arrows& & & & & & \\
     Communication of Papers & & & & & & \\};
  \foreach \cell in {2,3,4}
    {\cellarrow{2}{\cell}}
\end{tikzpicture}            

\section{Some other table}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[mymatr,
     column 1/.style={nodes={text width=width("Communication of Papers")}},
     column 9/.style={nodes={text width=width("~~")}},
     nodes={text height=3.5ex, text depth=2ex}
     ] (matr) {
     Some column & \done & \done & \done& \done& \done& \done &\done &\\
     This has arrows& & & & & & & & \\
     Communication of Papers & & & & & & & & \\};
  \foreach \cell in {7,8,9}
    {\cellarrow{2}{\cell}}
\end{tikzpicture}            
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\def\done{done}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__David_Arrow:nn
  {
    \tikz \draw [->,red,very~thick] 
             ( \int_eval:n { #1 + 1 } -| \int_eval:n { #2 + 1 } )
          -- ( #1 -| \int_eval:n { #2 + 1 } ) ; 
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \Arrow { }
  { 
    \tl_gput_right:Nx \g_nicematrix_code_after_tl
      { \__David_Arrow:nn { \arabic{iRow} } { \arabic{jCol} } }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Table with Same width}
\begin{NiceTabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Some column  & \done & \done &  \done&  \done& \done&\done \\
    \hline
    This has arrows& \Arrow & \Arrow & \Arrow & & &  \\
    \hline
    Communication of Papers & &  & &  & &    \\ \hline  
\end{NiceTabular}


\section{Some other table}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{NiceTabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Some column  & \done & \done &  \done&  \done&  \done& \done &\done  &\\
    \hline
    This has arrows&  &  &  &  & & \Arrow & \Arrow & \Arrow \\
    \hline
    Communication of Papers
    & &  & &  & &  & &  \\ \hline   
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations because of the PGF/Tikz nodes.

[image: Ouput of the above code]